# How to implement Data Scaffolding in .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding

I am going to start a project in ASP.Net and want to implement Data Scaffolding as it would be a good learning curve and the deadline is short. All i have understood till now is that Data Scaffolding is used to automatically create web pages accoring to data, to facilitate developer to write less code (Do less, Have More).

Can anyone provide me a good guide to do that thing? or some tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could google it with little effort: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx for MVC or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377606%28v=vs.100%29.aspx if you are using asp.net web forms